# How to patch small holes in concrete slab basement floor?

Tags: subfloor, cement

I am preparing to install luxury vinyl plank (LVP) in my basement (specifically [CoreTec Pro](https://coretecfloors.com/COREtec/media/Files/Instructions/SHA418_PROPLUS_InstallationInstructions_r2.pdf?ext=.pdf)). The subfloor is just concrete slab.

Previously this room had carpet with tack strips nailed to the cement. When I pulled up the old tack strips the nails pulled out small chunks of concrete (maybe 1/4 deep, 1-1.5 inches across).

What is the best approach to match these before I put down the vinyl floor (floating install)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variety of patch products.

[Premixed concrete patch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Concrete-Patch/1085955) would work.

[Platinum patch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Platinum-Patch/1000535775)

[Vinyl spackling](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-White-Spackling/3964011)

For holes that small i would use the vinyl spackling. You can sand it down if you are sloppy in the application.

I would not worry about holes smaller then a nickle or dime.

Clean and vacuum the holes out to insure good adhesion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the severity, a self-leveling compound is ideal. Lowes, Home Depot, etc... will have concrete floor patch. Get the self leveling kind.  If it's just a few places and the rest of the floor is perfectly smooth, you can patch with virtually anything to fill the void. Thin-set mortar would be my choice.